# Unacceptable hrtimer resolution with kernel-rt

Tags: kernel, real-time

I am running Centos 6.5.

I've installed a realtime kernel

## uname -a

Linux lx-rttargets 3.0.9-rt26.46.el6rt.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Wed Jan 25 09:38:18 CET 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I installed the rt kernel from a Scientific Linux repository at CERN:
http://glitesoft.cern.ch/cern/mrg/slc6X/x86_64/RPMS/

It claims to be using tsc as the clock source:

## cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource

tsc

BUT I'm not getting hrtimer support.

## cat /proc/timer_list | grep resolution | uniq

.resolution: 999848 nsecs

When I run cyclictest, it has a function check_timer() that calls clock_getres( CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts) which fails causing cyclictest to report "WARN: High resolution timers not available".

The output of cyclictest (which is awful) is what first caught my attention.

I get very bad results:

## ./cyclictest --smp -p95 -f -b 2000

gives average values over 1000 for many cpus generally.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on.  I've been working this for several days and have found nothing online to help yet.

Thanks.

Comment: SOLUTION:  After several days of banging my head on this, I've just discovered that removing the "acpi=off" kernel argument at boot time seems to make this problem go away.  Does anyone know why?!

Comment: I don't think the TSC can trigger interrupts, only report the current time. Therefore Linux needs a separate interrupt source. Without ACPI, you probably don't have a high resolution interrupt source, so it falls back on the standard system timer. Therefore, your scheduling granularity becomes 1/HZ, which defaults to 1ms for amd64 systems (even though you have much more accurate time reporting).

Comment: @crosstalk You should add this as answer. This helped me a lot.